# why isn't this google analytics event being logged?

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a new Google Analytics website. I've added the tracking code script block before . I'm sending a custom event to GA and no js error is thrown. However, when I navigate to Reporting > Behavior > Events > Overview, no events are displayed.  I haven't created any filters for this GA account that would block the request.  Any idea what the problem might be or next steps to debug?

Comment: Have you tried with the Google Analytics Debugger tool? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en It has helped me to identify tracking issues in the past. Also, check the network tab on the chrome developer tools, for each event you trigger there should be an interaction logged there.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code so the community may help.

Comment: Are you aware there is generally a next-day lag between when an event is sent to GA and when it is visible in the dashboard?